# TextView's setText method does not set the text, when I start the Activity second time

Tags: android, textview, settext

Before posting this question I googled a lot to find out this peculiar problem.
What I am doing that I am setting a text in a TextView inside a callback method.
This code works perfectly fine when I launch my app first time, but on the next time it does not update the TextView.
I've only got a single Activity and inside `onBackPressed()` I finish it.
Below is the code I have written to update the values of a location object in four different TextViews.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LocationApi.LocationResult{

private static final String TAG = Home.class.getSimpleName();
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private TextView txtLatitude;
private TextView txtLongitude;
private TextView txtAccuracy;
private TextView txtProvider;
private Context mContext;
//private MyLocationApi locationApi;
private LocationApi locationApi;

private StringBuilder logcat;
private int count =0;
private MyLocationApi.MyLocationDataListener myLocationListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    mContext = this;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    txtLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.val_lat);
    txtLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.val_lng);
    txtAccuracy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.val_accuracy);
    txtProvider = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.val_provider);

    //Code to get location using fused api (GoogleClientApi)
    locationApi = LocationApi.getInstance(mContext);
    locationApi.connect();
    Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate is called");

}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    Log.d(TAG, "On Start is called ");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "On Backpressed is called ");

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if(locationApi != null){
            locationApi.disconnect();
        }
        finish();
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    //DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


    return true;
}

@Override
public void gotLocation(Location _location) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Got Location is called");

    Log.d(TAG,"Lat "+Double.toString(_location.getLatitude()));
    Log.d(TAG,"Lng "+Double.toString(_location.getLongitude()));
    Log.d(TAG,"Acc " + Double.toString(_location.getAccuracy()));
    Log.d(TAG, "Prov " + _location.getProvider().toString());

    txtLatitude.setText(Double.toString(_location.getLatitude()));
    txtLongitude.setText(Double.toString(_location.getLongitude()));
    txtAccuracy.setText(Double.toString(_location.getAccuracy()));
    txtProvider.setText(_location.getProvider().toString());
    //locationApi.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void locationNotAvailable() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Location not available is called");
}
}
```

## **Logcat:**

```
02-01 12:41:16.721 13865-13865/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-01 12:41:17.071 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
02-01 12:41:17.071 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 254: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
02-01 12:41:17.071 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
02-01 12:41:17.071 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
02-01 12:41:17.071 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 18
02-01 12:41:17.071 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e7
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzah
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1595: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 27 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzj
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 549: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
02-01 12:41:17.081 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
02-01 12:41:17.121 13865-13888/com.binarysoft.nearme I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
02-01 12:41:17.131 13865-13888/com.binarysoft.nearme E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
02-01 12:41:17.141 13865-13888/com.binarysoft.nearme E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19485: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19489: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-01 12:41:17.291 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-01 12:41:17.672 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-01 12:41:17.672 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 627: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-01 12:41:17.672 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 12:41:17.672 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-01 12:41:17.672 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 649: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-01 12:41:17.672 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-01 12:41:17.682 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
02-01 12:41:17.682 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 20100: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
02-01 12:41:17.682 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
02-01 12:41:17.682 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
02-01 12:41:17.682 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 20100: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
02-01 12:41:17.682 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
02-01 12:41:18.042 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: OnCreate is called
02-01 12:41:18.042 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: On Start is called 
02-01 12:41:18.062 13865-13869/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 514K, 14% free 8945K/10352K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 31ms
02-01 12:41:18.713 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
02-01 12:41:18.733 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/ION: config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
02-01 12:41:18.733 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/MM_DEVICE: Waiting for mm thread to come up
02-01 12:41:18.733 13865-13916/com.binarysoft.nearme D/MM_DEVICE: mm_device_thread starting
02-01 12:41:18.743 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglCreateContext() config: 18 context: 0x51a12fc0, VC context 1, Thread 13865
02-01 12:41:18.743 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
02-01 12:41:18.753 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4fd89720, VC surface: 1, Thread: 13865
02-01 12:41:18.753 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(0x51a12fc0, 0x4fd89720, 0x4fd89720) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:41:18.763 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-01 12:41:18.773 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
02-01 12:41:18.773 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16146: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
02-01 12:41:18.773 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
02-01 12:41:19.153 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/WritingBuddyImpl: getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
02-01 12:41:19.233 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-01 12:41:19.243 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnConnected :: 
02-01 12:41:19.313 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnConnected :: Last Known Location: 77.0630103 , 28.4594539
02-01 12:41:19.313 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Connected is called
02-01 12:41:19.614 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnLocationChanged Called 1 timesNew Lat: 28.4594519 New Long: 77.06301
02-01 12:41:20.575 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: On Start is called 
02-01 12:41:20.925 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnLocationChanged Called 2 timesNew Lat: 28.4594525 New Long: 77.0630112
02-01 12:41:24.318 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Got Location is called
02-01 12:41:24.318 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Lat 28.4594525
02-01 12:41:24.318 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Lng 77.0630112
02-01 12:41:24.318 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Acc 24.0
02-01 12:41:24.318 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Prov fused
02-01 12:41:24.498 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/LocationApi: Update Timeout
02-01 12:41:59.482 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: On Start is called 
02-01 12:41:59.683 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/WritingBuddyImpl: getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
02-01 12:42:01.134 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: On Backpressed is called 
02-01 12:42:01.454 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:01.454 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4fd89720, android window 0x4fd813e0, Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:01.865 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(0x51a12fc0, 0x53fa3158, 0x53fa3158) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:01.865 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:01.885 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(0x51a12fc0, 0x53fa3158, 0x53fa3158) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:01.885 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:13.286 13865-13869/com.binarysoft.nearme D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 256K, 12% free 9188K/10352K, paused 24ms+6ms, total 160ms
02-01 12:42:13.296 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: OnCreate is called
02-01 12:42:13.296 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: On Start is called 
02-01 12:42:13.396 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
02-01 12:42:13.396 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x53f77070, VC surface: 3, Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:13.396 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/HAWAII_EGL: eglMakeCurrent(0x51a12fc0, 0x53f77070, 0x53f77070) Thread: 13865
02-01 12:42:13.516 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/WritingBuddyImpl: getCurrentWritingBuddyView() 
02-01 12:42:13.616 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnConnected :: 
02-01 12:42:13.656 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnConnected :: Last Known Location: 77.0630112 , 28.4594525
02-01 12:42:13.656 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Connected is called
02-01 12:42:13.726 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnLocationChanged Called 1 timesNew Lat: 28.4594525 New Long: 77.0630112
02-01 12:42:14.817 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme I/LocationApi: OnLocationChanged Called 2 timesNew Lat: 28.4594525 New Long: 77.0630112
02-01 12:42:18.651 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Got Location is called
02-01 12:42:18.651 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Lat 28.4594525
02-01 12:42:18.651 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Lng 77.0630112
02-01 12:42:18.651 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Acc 24.0
02-01 12:42:18.651 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: Prov fused
02-01 12:42:18.661 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/LocationApi: Update Timeout
02-01 12:42:44.617 13865-13865/com.binarysoft.nearme D/Home: On Start is called
```

=============
`gotLocation()` is the method where I am getting the values from the location object, but it does not appear in the TextView.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you really think this method (`gotLocation`) is fired?

Comment: Yeah, is it fired? Can you see the log cat? Is yes? then is it null or have some value?

Comment: There is no logcat at all, in your post.

Comment: Sorry! I added the logcat. Log after the "On Backpressed is called " is logged when I ran the app second time

Answer (score 0):

editText method is not in oncreate method.

```
@Override public void gotLocation(Location _location) { Log.d(TAG,"Got Location is called"); Log.d(TAG,"Lat "+Double.toString(_location.getLatitude())); Log.d(TAG,"Lng "+Double.toString(_location.getLongitude())); Log.d(TAG,"Acc " + Double.toString(_location.getAccuracy())); Log.d(TAG, "Prov " + _location.getProvider().toString()); txtLatitude.setText(Double.toString(_location.getLatitude())); txtLongitude.setText(Double.toString(_location.getLongitude())); txtAccuracy.setText(Double.toString(_location.getAccuracy())); txtProvider.setText(_location.getProvider().toString()); //locationApi.disconnect(); }
```

You can use recreate method by pressing crtl+O

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. There is not editText. I have declared TextView on module level. Initialized them on "OnCreate". and use them inside the callback method.

Comment: @Ashish Sorry, it's my fault